# Docker Desktop cannot set large disk size

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm running Docker Desktop 2.2.0 on Windows 10. It appears that the disk size cannot be set beyond 64GB. I tried setting the diskSizeMiB value to 100GB in %APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json, but docker appears to ignore it and set the size to 64GB in the resulting Hyper-V VM.

```
    "cpus": 6,
    "diskSizeMiB": 102400,
```

The issue I'm having is older images being evicted when pulling new ones in. Even when manually expanding the HyperV disk to 100GB, `docker pull` deletes older images to make space for new ones.

[Docker for Windows docs](https://docs.docker.com/ee/desktop/admin/configure/windows-admin/) don't seem to explicitly mention a limit, but 64Gb ominously equals 2^16 bytes which hints at it being a technical limit.

Anyone knows of a workaround for this limitation?

Comment: If you are not dependent on features of enterprise edition, I suggest you try the community edition.   

With `WSL2` option in community edition, you will not have any kind of limit what-so-ever.

Comment: @ABMRuman - I didn't know about the WSL support, so thanks for pointing that out. Sadly, our Enterprise Windows 10 is at 1809 and Docker WSL 2 requires build 19018 or above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was on the right track with increasing the virtual disk size directly in Hyper-V (See [this guide](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/increase-disk-size-hyper-v-complete-guide/)). The only missing piece was restarting Docker (or Windows). Once restarted, I was able to use the full disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but after updating to Docker Desktop 4.24.1 the Settings > Resources > Advanced UI seems to have been fixed.

The Virtual Disk Limit slider now goes well above 64GB and is limited only by the size of my drive.